# get_posts() using an array of post ids

Tags: get-posts, array

There's an array of post ids, and I'd like to use it to load these particular posts. I'm using get_posts() but there's some kind of problem using an array for 'post__in' argument.

Here are the contents of the array:

Array ( [0] => 44376 [1] => 44371 [2] => 44387 [3] => 44395 [4] => 44334 )

And here's the PHP code:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $post_ids;
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

I tried using explode() to convert the array but didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `get_posts()` returning? An empty array? Are those IDs ones of posts with post type `post` and with status `publish`?

Comment: Yes, all posts are published. I'm getting a blank page so I guess that there must be some kind of php error, and it has to do with the array.

Comment: Just for interest sake, what happens if you manually add the I'd's to `post__in`.

Comment: What errors do you get if you turn debugging on and how exactly are you getting the post I'd's

Comment: Are the IDs in the array valid and are you sure they are published? I'm also thinking that this could be a problem related to the default `offset` and/or `posts_per_page` arguments, try setting `posts_per_page => -1`, since this should make the query ignore the offset value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this instead:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

**Lesson learned**: *Always check your PHP scripting errors!* ;-)

Check for example [this Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) on debugging.

Comment: Crap, missed that as well. Lesson learned :-)

Comment: Just a note. Don't forget to add `'post_type'=>'custom_post_type'` in case you're targeting a custom post type.